# SimpleBlobDetector not recognizing the more obvious circles

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, geometry, detection

I am using SimpleBlobDetector with the parameters specified below:

```
# Parameters
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 1500
params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.5
params.filterByConvexity = True
params.minConvexity = 0.9
params.filterByInertia = True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.7
params.minDistBetweenBlobs = 10
params.filterByColor = False

# Create a detector with the parameters
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector(params)
keypoints = detector.detect(dilated)
im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(dilated, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255),cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

# Display result
cv2.imshow("Keypoints", im_with_keypoints)
```

This produces the result below. As you can see, some of the 'cleaner' circles are not detected whilst others which have rougher edges are detected. What could be the problem please?

[image: result of SimpleBlobDetector]

Comment: So, I'm on a phone and can't do any debugging, but have you sanity checked the object features to make sure that they all fall within your filter parameters?

Comment: Yes, I tried making the filtering parameters very wide to catch as many blobs as possible, however the problem still occured

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add

params.maxArea = 10000

you get this image:

[image: not too big to fail]

so I assume there's a default maximum, and you're exceeding it.

Comment: Just wanted to add a thank you to the person who gave this answer, since this answered a question I was about to ask on here perfectly.

Comment: This was great @mcduffee :)

Comment: The default for maxArea is 5000.  More defaults for SimpleBlobDetector_Params() are here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/blobdetector.cpp